# Is there a way to display a fan chart in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, montecarlo

I have the results of a [Monte Carlo simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) over 1000 paths along a time series (100 years). I would like to display this in PowerBI as a [fan chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_chart_(time_series)). The `Line chart` visual cannot be used for this, as it is limited to 33 legend items (i.e., 33 paths, in my case). I have tried to use a filter on paths by only displaying the top N paths and the bottom N paths, but the `Line chart` visual does not allow for both applying a top **and** and bottom filter.

Is there a PowerBI visual which can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you want but I've approached this sort of thing by defining measures for different percentiles or standard deviations similar in concept to this chart:

[image: Example Chart]

You can either define the measures separately and not use the Legend field or else create a parameter table for the various percentiles / standard deviations with a measure that reads in that parameter.